# File are corrupted when Attaching them to MailMessage C#

Tags: c#, .net, attachment, smtpclient

I have created an application at work that generates exel files from some database data. After generating the files they are sent automatically to the customers in question. My problem is that it works fine when i run the published application. But some users when they run the application the files are generated perfectly as they are saved on the HDD and i can see them. But when they are attached to the MailMessage object they get corrupted. This is an image of the corrupted files. These files should be Excel files.

[image]

This is my code for sending a mail with attached files:

```
public void SendMailedFilesDK()
        {
            string[] sentFiles = Directory.GetFiles(sentFilesDK);
            if (sentFiles.Count() > 0)
            {
                using (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("ares"))
                {
                    using (System.Net.Mail.MailMessage msg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage())
                    {
                        msg.From = new MailAddress("system@mail.dk");
                        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("operation@mail.dk"));
                        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("bl@mail.dk"));
                        msg.CC.Add("lmy@mail.dk");
                        msg.CC.Add("ltr@mail.dk");
                        msg.Subject = "IBM PUDO";
                        msg.Body = sentFiles.Count() + " attached file(s) has been sent to the customer(s) in question ";
                        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
                        foreach (string file in sentFiles)
                        {
                            Attachment attachment = new Attachment(file);
                            msg.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                        }

                        client.Send(msg);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Why are the files getting corrupted when others run the application? We are all using office 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure to set the content type of the attachement to the appropriate value.

`application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` for xlsx files, or

`application/vnd.ms-excel` for xls files.

For example, your loop should look something like this.

```
ContentType xlsxContent = new ContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
foreach (string file in sentFiles)
{
    Attachment attachment = new Attachment(file, xlsxContent);
    msg.Attachments.Add(attachment);
}
```

Comment: What should i write if it is a Zip file i need to attatch ? i have tried to insert this line: **Attachment attachment = new Attachment(zipFile, MediaTypeNames.Application.Zip);**  but it didnt work. I am using **DotNetZipLib-DevKit-v1.9**

Comment: found it. I have to use `application/zip`

Answer (score 1):

We use this in our Attachment constructor and have no issues attaching Excel and PDF.

Attachment data = new Attachment(sFileName, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);

Also check that the users running this have permissions to access the files in whatever location is specified by *sentFilesDK*.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to specify the mimetype which is part of one of the constructors on Attachment class.

*public Attachment(string fileName, ContentType contentType);*

You can also read the file in memorystream and pass it as part of the following constructor.

*public Attachment(Stream contentStream, string name, string mediaType);*